# How to style the <h1> for each of these flexbox classes separately?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to style the `<h1>` text (text-align, font size etc.) differently for each of these flex boxes. 
I tried to do it but it has not worked.
I took the code flexbox code from an answer on this site and I am not sure what the programmer has done e.g. I don't know what `.wrapper > .box-wrap > .box:last-child` means.

Please would you modify my code. Thank you.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper > * {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
}
.wrapper > .box-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.wrapper > .box-wrap > .box {
  flex:1;
  margin: 5px;
}
.wrapper > .box-wrap > .box:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.wrapper > .box-wrap > .box:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid;
}


.wrapper h1{
font-size:15px; font-style:italic; color:#555; text-align: left;
}

.box-wrap h1{
font-size:22px; color:#777; text-align:right;
}

.box h1{
font-size:32px; color:#CC000; text-align:right;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .box h1, h1{
  text-align:center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content ="ie=edge">




<title>Test</title>

<style>

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper > * {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
}
.wrapper > .box-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.wrapper > .box-wrap > .box {
  flex:1;
  margin: 5px;
}
.wrapper > .box-wrap > .box:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.wrapper > .box-wrap > .box:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid;
}


.wrapper h1{
font-size:15px; font-style:italic; color:#555; text-align: left;
}

.box-wrap h1{
font-size:22px; color:#777; text-align:right;
}

.box h1{
font-size:32px; color:#CC000; text-align:right;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .box h1, h1{
  text-align:center;
  }
}



</style>
</head>



<body>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Wrapper</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box-wrap">
    <div class="box">
      <h1>Box-wrap</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h1>Box</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<header>



</body>
```

Comment: I am guessing that some of the boxes inherit properties from one of the boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to edit HTML/CSS code, you should at least learn the basics of it; The whole idea of CSS is styling your HTML elements which can be targeted using *selectors* (classes, ids, pseudo-elements); these selectors can be combined to alter the *[specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)* of the targeted element, which lets you select from a general element to a very specific and unique one.

With the line `.wrapper > .box-wrap > .box:last-child` you are telling your CSS to target the `.box` element that is last element and is also a direct child of the `.box-wrap` element, which again is the direct child of the `.wrapper` element

In your case, if you have three `h1` elements which are NOT children of the same parent,  the simplest approach would be adding a class specific to each of them, and then add the styles to that CSS class. Like this:

```css
.heading {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.h1 {
  color: red;
}

.h2 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.h3 {
  color: green;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="heading h1">Heading 1</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1 class="heading h2">Heading 2</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h1 class="heading h3">Heading 3</h1>
</div>
```

With your code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper>* {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
}

.wrapper>.box-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.wrapper>.box-wrap>.box {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
}

.wrapper>.box-wrap>.box:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.wrapper>.box-wrap>.box:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.wrapper h1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #555;
  text-align: left;
}

.box-wrap h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #777;
  text-align: right;
}

.box .header1 {
  color: red;
}

.box .header2 {
  color: green;
}

.box .header3 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">




  <title>Test</title>

  <style>
    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .wrapper>* {
      flex: 1;
      margin: 5px;
    }
    
    .wrapper>.box-wrap {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .wrapper>.box-wrap>.box {
      flex: 1;
      margin: 5px;
    }
    
    .wrapper>.box-wrap>.box:first-child {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    
    .wrapper>.box-wrap>.box:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .box {
      border: 1px solid;
    }
    
    .wrapper h1 {
      font-size: 15px;
      font-style: italic;
      color: #555;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .box-wrap h1 {
      font-size: 22px;
      color: #777;
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    .box h1 {
      font-size: 32px;
      color: #CC000;
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .wrapper {
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .box h1,
      h1 {
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>



<body>


  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
      <h1 class="header1">Wrapper</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrap">
      <div class="box">
        <h1 class="header2">Box-wrap</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <h1 class="header3">Box</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid showing more than one of the same h tag at a time. Regardless, you could just give each of them an id attribute to give them their "unique" touch.

```
<h1 id="whatever_you_wanna_call_this">Sample text</h1>
```

Comment: thanks. That is what I did at first but the <h1> style also has to change under a @media (max-width: 768px) query (I need to centre align the text when the screen is reduced), so I was told that I have to style the <h1> in the css.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector `.wrapper > .box-wrap > .box:last-child` selects the `last` child element with class=`box` of children elements with class=`box-wrap` of elements with class=`wrapper`. (See: [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp))

```
<div class="wrapper">        <- elements with class=wrapper
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box-wrap">     <- elements with class=box-wrap
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>  <- last element with class=box
  </div>
</div>
```

You can assign a unique ID to each `h1` element and define its style in CSS, or use inline CSS (See: [HTML Styles - CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp))

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by saying, it's best practice to only include ONE h1 on a page though. All others should be `h2`, `h3`, etc. That's best for SEO, semantics, and accessibility (unless you're adding other h1's inside a `section` or `article` tag). If you want to style different h2's differently, I'd suggest adding content-based classes to define *why* you're styling them differently, something like `.intro h2` or `.hero-article h2`.

That said, I've added the effective CSS selectors next to each element.

The `>` combinator means to "only select the `.box` that is a direct child of `.wrapper` (not any descendant).

In order to target different `h1`s within the `.box-wrap .box h1` structure, you'll want to add distinct classes (don't use id's to style), or use pseudo selectors like `.box-wrap .box:first-child h1`, `.box-wrap .box:last-child h1`, or `.box-wrap .box:nth-child(odd) h1`, etc.

```
<div class="wrapper"> <!-- .wrapper -->
  <div class="box"> <!-- .wrapper > .box -->
    <h1>Wrapper</h1> <!-- .wrapper > .box h1 -->
  </div>
  <div class="box-wrap"> <!-- .box-wrap -->
    <div class="box"> <!-- .box-wrap .box -->
      <h1>Box-wrap</h1> <!-- .box-wrap .box h1 -->
    </div>
    <div class="box"> <!-- .box-wrap .box -->
      <h1>Box</h1> <!-- .box-wrap .box h1 -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are seeing in the existing code, selecting elements in CSS like this is hard to understand, and very specific for the order and structure of your html.

The recommended way would be to add classes to the h1 or the .box, so you can style them more directly.

```
<h1 class="small-italic">

.small-italic {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

or

```
<div class="box small-italic-headline">

.small-italic-headline h1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

As you can see, you can also assign multiple classes to an element.

Concerning the code you copied:

You can imagine selector using [the > combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) like a path or address in your DOM tree.

For your first h1, the "address" would be `.wrapper > .box > h1`. Each > means you're adding a selector for a direct child element.

In your own styles, you're using the [decsendent combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) which means you're adding a selector for an element that's somewhere inside the parent.

So `.wrapper h1` matches all your h1, because they are all inside the wrapper element.

The same goes for your second selector `.box h1`: all the h1 are inside a .box element.

`.box-wrap h1` will address two of your h1, those that are somewhere inside the .box-wrap element.